# Can't set cookie in Wordpress plugin after theme has started rendering

Tags: php, wordpress, header

When I set a cookie in a Wordpress plugin, I get the "headers already sent" error. Can someone suggest how I can fix this?

> Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/53/7742253/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyten/header.php:11) in /home/content/53/7742253/html/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 692,693,694

my code:-

```
     if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && !is_user_logged_in())

      {

         require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php' );


    $registration = get_option( 'users_can_register' );

       global $wpdb;

       $user_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM              

                  $wpdb->usermeta           WHERE 

                meta_key = 'id' AND meta_value =%s",$id) );

         if ( empty($user_id) ) 
              {

                 $wp_user_obj = get_user_by('email', $email);

                $user_id = $wp_user_obj->ID;

               }

               if ( $user_id)

                  {

                   wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );

                      wp_set_current_user( $user_id );

               if ( isset( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) && !empty( 
           $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) 
            {

              wp_redirect( home_url() );

                 }
                 else 
               {

                wp_redirect(home_url() );

                 }

                   }      

                     else

                   {

                   $userdata = array();


                $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata );

                 wp_new_user_notification($user_id,$user_pass);

                  if ( $user_id )
                     {

                         $creds = array();

                        $creds['user_login'] = $username;

                         $creds['user_password'] = $user_pass;

                          if ( !empty( $remember ) )
                            { 

                             $creds['remember'] = true;

                                 }

                    $user = wp_signon( $creds, true );  

                     update_usermeta( $user_id,'id',esc_attr( $_REQUEST['id']));

                 update_usermeta( $user_id,'fname',esc_attr( $_REQUEST['fname']));

                   update_usermeta( $user_id,'lname',$_REQUEST['lname']);

              update_usermeta( $user_id, 'email',esc_attr( $_REQUEST['email']) );

                 wp_redirect(home_url() );

               }

                }

               }    

             global $user_ID; $user = get_userdata( $user_ID );

           if(is_user_logged_in())
         {

                echo $user->user_login ; 

              } 



and heder.php line:-  `<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>`
```

Comment: Make sure that there is no kind of output before setting the cookie, maybe a blank line or another module already outputting something.

Comment: I wonder if we have some sort of FAQ for the PHP Headers already sent scenario caused by using `header`, `session` or `set_cookie`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+modify+header+information+php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling your `set_cookies` function too late. At the time you call it, output has already started. You need call it before any output has started, because cookies can not be set if output has already started (see as well: [`setcookie`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)).

In your case before `header.php` line 11 is being executed.

That's merely [before the theme get's loaded](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aR5G9DUj0pTsJ%3atoolpress.de/tools/Toolpress_-_Wordpress-3.0-Program-Flow-0.2-2010-06-28.pdf+toolpress+wordpress+program+flow&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESij1Sg5Xi-QYoMggSTynSlto_A-X20Y9x0MGA410lYK8MdRagDjc1hZi4x3H-4_F_MUgigDVzXuPHvej5vot7EKoknL9TAxRQAGqR7KhSJc9iVleXAV1azwGxdTlhg0fUG_jvge&sig=AHIEtbSsLJQNCXcePVZ6CjNdO-YS3rVh4g).

Comment: hii hakre thanks but not work please see my full code and then suggest me

Comment: Sure it works, you just need to set the cookies before any output has done to the browser. You can check with [`headers_sent()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php). If that function returns true, do not set any headers. Put an if condition around your set cookies or move it up in the program flow where it returns false. Then you won't see this error any longer.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid header modification warning messages by buffering your source, before it makes it to the browser. If you do not have access to php.ini you can add `php_value output_buffering 4096` to your .htaccess or you can add `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");` at the top and `ob_end_flush()` at the bottom of your wordpresses root index.php