# wordpress get_header function error

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the twenty elevan theme of the wordpress. my pages showing only page content without style and header content. when I logged in admin then it is showing the pages in style with header content.Please let me know why the header and footer function is not working when I logged out.How can I fix this?

```
http://govirtualassistants.com/



    <?php
     /**
  * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
* @package WordPress
 *  @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
```

*   @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
    /
      ?>
        
     >
        
        
           >
       
       
        >
       
      
      >
      
      
        " />
       
         
     * Print the  tag based on what is being viewed.
     */
    global $page, $paged;

```
wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

// Add the blog name.
bloginfo( 'name' );

// Add the blog description for the home/front page.
$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
    echo " | $site_description";

  // Add a page number if necessary:
  if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
    echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyeleven' ), max( $paged, $page )                    );

 ?></title>
 <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
  href="<?php bloginfo(     'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"                
    type="text/javascript">
   </script>
     <![endif]-->
     <?php
/* We add some JavaScript to pages with the comment form
 * to support sites with threaded comments (when in use).
 */
if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

/* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
 * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
 * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
 * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
 */
wp_head();
      ?>
         </head>

       <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
         <div id="page" class="hfeed">
 <header id="branding" role="banner">

          <nav id="access" role="navigation">
            <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
            <?php /* Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>
            <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
            <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
            <?php /* Our navigation menu. If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu. The menu assigned to the primary location is the one used. If one isn't assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used. */ ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #access -->
</header><!-- #branding -->


<div id="main">
```

Comment: can you post a link to the site in question?

Comment: http://govirtualassistants.com/

Comment: this link wouid be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955293/when-i-set-cookie-in-wordpress-plugin-then-header-already-sent-problem-appear-li

Answer (score 0):

if you open your page.php or index.php

make sure the call to the wordpress header is there and NOT commented out!

ie

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

I see your other pages and posts are loading fine, 
if you have set your homepage to be a page, or using a different page template, double check that call to the wp head is still their.

Marty

Comment: if you look at the source code for the homepage it starts just after the navigation, but if you go to your about page, the page loads fine, which to me, would mean the page template or index file is not loading the header code, do you have any custom code in the header? or your functions file? ie: if(is_admin()) {

Comment: Also, disable the wp-cache plugin! until the site is finished and ready to make LIVE, you wont really need this.. get all your site sorted first then activate it!